# Apache Flink : Watermarks per partitions?

Tags: apache-flink

I see that there are lot of discussions going on about adding support for watermarks per key. But do flink support per partition watermarks?

Currently - then minimum of all the watermarks(non idle partitions) is taken into account. Because of this the last hanging records in a window are stuck as well.(when incremented the watermark using periodicemit)

Any info on this is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Some of the sources, such as the `FlinkKafkaConsumer`, support per-partition watermarking. You get this by calling `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on the source, rather than on the stream produced by the source.

What this does is that each consumer instance tracks the maximum timestamp within each partition, and take as its watermark the minimum of these maximums, less the configured bounded out-of-orderness. Idle partitions will be ignored, if you configure it to do so.

Not only does this yield more accurate watermarking, but if your events are in-order within each partition, this also makes it possible to take advantage of the `WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps()` strategy.

See [Watermark Strategies and the Kafka Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#watermark-strategies-and-the-kafka-connector) for more details.

As for why the last window isn't being triggered, this is related to watermarking, but not to per-partition watermarking. The problem is simply that windows are triggered by watermarks, and the watermarks are trailing behind the timestamps in the events. So the watermarks can never catch up to the final events, and can never trigger the last window.

This isn't a problem for unbounded streaming jobs, since they never stop and never have a last window. And it isn't a problem for batch jobs, since they are aware of all of the data. But for bounded streaming jobs, you need to do something to work around this issue. Broadly speaking, what you must do is to inform Flink that the input stream has ended -- whenever the Flink sources detect that they have reached the end of an event-time-based input stream, they emit one last watermark whose value is MAX_WATERMARK, and this will trigger any open windows.

One way to do this is to use a `KafkaDeserializationSchema` with an implementation of `isEndOfStream` that returns true when the job reaches its end.

Comment: Thanks david - I am using the water marking at source(kafka consumer level here) - even though the watermarks are maintained at partition level, when they are being sent to other operators, flink is actually calculating the min of all of them and sending it out.

I got it by debugging in StatusWatermarkValve.class, When i have data in multiple partitions with different event timestamps (as i cannot guarantee the order) - the min of all those timestamps are sent to operator. Am i missing something here?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: If i have 3 partitions and 3 task manager with 1 task slot inside each TM allocated to each partitions, then would there be 3 watermarks(1 for each TM/Partitions) or 1 watermark(which is min of all those 3?) . i have tested this scenario and it seems only one watermark(the min of all 3) are sent to all the TMs. But the documentation says that we can have watermarks per partition if we set them at source level. I will add more details to my question. Can you please check and explain whats going on?

Comment: Each slot will do its own independent watermarking. There is no global coordination of the watermarks across different slots or TMs. However, any task with multiple inputs (e.g., after a keyBy) will use the minimum of the incoming watermarks as its own watermark.

Comment: thank you - Specifically - how does the keyBy operator works? Does it repartition the stream and allocate the record to some other task manager? In my case - i am making sure that the records with same key are being sent to same partition , but they still end up in some other different task manager after being consumed in the first one. This might be the reason for watermarks propagation as well. eg : If i send 6 records (3 diff keys) to 3 partitions - they are consumed by 3 TMs but end up in a different TM after the  keyBy operator.

Comment: Each task manager (TM) is responsible for some subset of the keys. keyBy repartitions the stream so that every record is sent to the TM responsible for that record's key -- which guarantees that all records for a specific key are processed by the same TM. Even if all records with the same key are in the same partition, that doesn't mean than the TM that reads some events will be the TM assigned to handle those keys.